# Ubuntu 14.04 install fail

Tags: software-installation

I have a HP Pavilion G60 lap top running Ubuntu 14.04. 2 days ago it upgraded to 15.04 and restarted, now it wont run off the hard drive. I put a new hard drive in formatted it with a fresh install 14.04 and its still the same.I have to run off the Cd to use it. What can be wrong? It's has 1tb hard drive, 8gb ram, dual core 2.4 gig processors.